# How to update a customized object in a public api in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular8, rxjs-observables

I fetch data from json.typicode.com that is the public fake rest api and convert that json into object by getting my required number of fields now if I want to update that object would there be any mismatch for type or something or I need to perform anything extra?

I have an interface called User with certain number of fields

```
export interface  User {
    id: number;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    phone: string;
    username: string;
}
```

I am fetching data from fake Rest api that is

```
public getUsers():Observable<User[]>{
    return this.http.get<User[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
}
```

so the above code is written in a service which I inject in my ts file

if you will hit https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users in browser you will get the Json Objects like below

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

I am able to map the Data by using the Map function and getting only those fields which I want.

But now If I want to update users the problem would be how to update the Data with my custom Object that is different from the api json?

Comment: can you just make it more clear as it is not clear what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I fetch the api from json.typicode.com and build my own custom object getting the required fields from it now I want to update the same object so would there be mismatch while update? Or how would I do or I wont get any errors as I will pass my custom object to update the object that resides in that api...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible with the scenario I am working with the fake Rest api one just need to update the particular fields and can pass the custom object to the service for update no conversion is needed..!!

here is the code

```
public updateUser(user:User):Observable<User>{
  return this.http.put<User>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"+user.id,user);
}
```

So if the object is of type say the interface in the question then one must only need to update the required fields and need to pass in the service and can retrieve for the same as

```
this._usersService.updateUser(elementObj).subscribe(user=>{
      console.log(user)
    });
```

This will get you the object of updated Users..!!

Hope it could help the upcoming newbies..!!